# Error while extracting xml from a clob column

Tags: xml, oracle11g

I have a Clob column in a table which contains xml data.
I try to extract the data by writing a query:

```
select XMLTYPE.createxml(e.cdxml_index).extract('//page/fragment/text()') from chemical_structures e where e.primary_key=20;
```

The error message i get is:

Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-31020: The operation is not allowed, Reason: For security reasons, ftp and http access over XDB repository is not allowed on server side
ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 5
31020. 00000 -  "The operation is not allowed, Reason: %s"
*Cause:    The operation attempted is not allowed
*Action:   See reason and change to a valid operation.

Data in the clob column is as follows:

```
(CLOB) <?xml version="1.0"  ?>
<!DOCTYPE CDXML SYSTEM "http://www.***.com/xml/cdxml.dtd" >
<CDXML
 <page
 id="12"
 BoundingBox="0 0 540 719.75"
><fragment
 id="9"
 BoundingBox="91.5 111.75 104.01 123.21"
><n
id="8"
p="94.94 117.6"
Z="2"
Element="35"
NumHydrogens="0"
Charge="-1"
AS="N"
><t
id="7"
p="91.5 121.5"
BoundingBox="91.5 111.75 104.01 123.21"
><s font="3" size="10" face="96">Br-</s></t></n></fragment></page></CDXML>
```

I read on a forum that is has something to do with the DOCTYPE declaration in the xml.

can anyone suggest a way by which i can make it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a workaround.

I had to disable xml dtd validation but that didnt work after trying out a few things mentioned on various discussion boards.

Finally i decided to ignore the doctype declaration in the xml. To do that i used a REGEXP_REPLACE method.

The following query gave me what i was looking for:

```
select extract(XMLTYPE(REGEXP_REPLACE(e.cdxml_index, '<!DOCTYPE CDXML SYSTEM "http://***/xml/cdxml.dtd" >', '')),'//page/fragment/n') from chemical_structures e where e.primary_key=20;
```

I get the following output:

```
<n
id="8"
p="94.94 117.6"
Z="2"
Element="35"
NumHydrogens="0"
Charge="-1"
AS="N"
><t
id="7"
p="91.5 121.5"
BoundingBox="91.5 111.75 104.01 123.21"
><s font="3" size="10" face="96">Br-</s></t></n>
```

Comment: I tried disabling DTD with event 31156 at level 2, but then I get "LPX-00225: end-element tag "HEAD" does not match start-element tag "META"".  If I remove the DTD from the document altogether, or try REGEXP_REPLACE, as you did, again I get LPX-00225.  Any thoughts?